# Selenium Browser profile is logging to SSO using default user details rather using passed credentials

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, single-sign-on, microsoft-edge

Up until last last week my selenium UI tests were running successfully to log into system using SSO (with the test account details that I pass in the URL). If i don't pass the details it use to fail the test as there were no details entered in the auth popup. This is expected behaviour as Selenium will launch a New clean profile which doesn't have any stored details.

I'm always logged into the system hence when I normally open the browser manually the default profile is launched which logs me in automatically using SSO.

Now when I open incognito mode and try to log into the Site it asks for sign in details since the incognito mode doesn't have my details stored. this is also the expected behaviour

Since yesterday I noticed when I run the selenium UI tests it is ignoring the details I pass in the URL and keeps logging in as myself. I can confirm that it is using the new clean profile. I always delete cookies before launching browser
`driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`

no code change happened since 2 week, and the test started failing since yesterday, So i cannot blame the code. Also this happens on Chrome and new MS edge. I cannot confirm on firefox since our organization doesn't support it.
I tried running the tests on other developer machine and result is same, the test were passing on their machine before but not now. I checked with the Security team and they confirmed they made no changes to SSO since a long time. not sure how to debug this. below are the things i tried from my side

1. Changed the system password twice - no luck
2. restarted win twice (hard turn off and turn on) - no luck
3. test works in Jenkins as expected since this was no default SSO in jenkins server(win server) stored.

can anyone please help to solve or actually understand the issue.

Browser - Chrome 86.0.4240.198 and Edge 86.0.622.69
selenium - 3.141
JDK - 1.8.0
OS - Win 10

Comment: Include your driver initialization code and teardown.  You should also mention whether this site is an intranet.  btw, you really shouldn't be able to pass in login details via a URL.  Post is better security-wise.  (gets tend to be logged...)

Comment: For testing purposes, can you try to logout from your default profile and use any local email id for the default profile and check whether your code starts login using the passed credentials? For testing purposes, I suggest making a test with other channels of the Edge browser to verify whether the issue can be producible with it or not. If possible for you then try to share the sample code. It can help us to make a test on our side.